# How can i hide the address bar of FCKeditor when the browse server button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, frameset

i have a security issue and if anyone can help me i would be really great full,, the problem is the following on an old site is installed FCKeditor,, so when the user press the create a link or insert image button the editor pop up a new window,,

so after pressing the 'browse server' button then a new window appears,,, **BUT with showing the address bar..**

**how can i hide somehow the address bar of the new window**?? is this possible?? i know that modern browsers on using frameset etc is not possible to hide the address bar..

is this possible? any ideas that this would be achieved on another way Guys? maybe with js but were and what? i have all the source files..
If someone has already done that please please advice me how to solve this cause i m trying for ages to achieve that with no luck.. :(

once thank you all..

Really sorry but stackoverflow allows image upload on more than 10 reputation...

Comment: what about using some lightbox?

Comment: Thank you rogelio for the quick answer, i m sorry for not mentioning but its an oracle site installation smthng that i m not so relevant with, and i was wondering if you know were to insert the required javascript for both the buttons so to use the lightbox,, yeas u r right a modal would solve my problem,, but were is the question.. :(

Comment: if anyone wants to understand better the issue i have a link for this forum as well, any help is kindly accepted guys, the link is the following  http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Security-Issue-on-FCKEditor-2.6.3-after-pressing-the-Browse-Server-Button

Comment: I think the answer is ovbious, migrate to CKeditor. If a software isn't updated for many years, is time to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case someone else need it guys,

the problem was that in the

\FCKeditor\editor\filemanager\connectors\php\connector.php

someone has put

$Config['Enabled'] = true;

i made this a comment and now its not public the filemanager

//$Config['Enabled'] = true;

problem solved.. :)